# add Magento product attributes

Tags: php, magento

I use Magento 1.5.1.0.
I want to add products via PHP script.
I have a custom attribute set with 8 custom attributes, how I add value to the custom attributes via php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $host = "127.0.0.1/magento/index.php"; //our online shop url
     $client = new SoapClient('http://'.$host.'/api/soap/?wsdl'); //soap handle
     $apiuser= "user"; //webservice user login
     $apikey = "pw"; //webservice user pass

     $sess_id= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey); //we do login
     $attributeSets = $client->call($sess_id, 'product_attribute_set.list');
     $set = current($attributeSets);

    $newProductData = array(
                      'name'              => 'name'
                   // websites - Array of website ids to which you want to assign a new product
                    , 'websites'          => array(1) // array(1,2,3,...)
                    , 'short_description' => 'short'
                    , 'description'       => 'description'
                    , 'status'            => 'status'
                    , 'your_attributes'   => $value
                    , 'your_attributes2'   => $value
                    , 'your_attributes3'   => $value
                      and so on 
                  );

  try {  
  $client->call($sess_id, 'product.create', array('simple', $set['set_id'], 'sku_of_product', $newProductData));
  }
  catch (Exception $e) { //while an error has occured
  echo "==> Error: ".$e->getMessage(); //we print this 
  }
```

Hf&GL :D

Regards Boti

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is that i dont have Soap activated on my server. There is other way?

Answer (score 1):

via SOAP with product.create or product.update if it's exist already

```
$newProductData = array('name' => 'name',
                        'your_attribute' => $value
                        ,'your_attribute2' => $value  
                         );

 $proxy->call($sessionid, 'product.create', array('simple', $set['set_id'], sku, $newProductData));
```

Then the products will be created with your custom Attribute(s).

Regards boti

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, can you show me how the all php file must look like. I saw in magento example $proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$attributeSets = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_attribute_set.list');
$set = current($attributeSets); Best Regards

Comment: Yes , this is working fine for me. It will only work for V1 soap api

Answer (score 1):

Because I found this response in my search for doing the same thing with a later version of the SOAP API V2, I am adding the solution I finally came up with.

For the V2 SOAP API it appears that we need to nest the additional_attributes in a multi_data or single_data layer?

Looking at app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php #256 I think we need to use

```
$manufacturer = new stdClass();
$manufacturer->key = "manufacturer";
$manufacturer->value = "20";
$additionalAttrs['single_data'][] = $manufacturer;
```

or

```
$manufacturer = new stdClass();
$manufacturer->key = "manufacturer";
$manufacturer->value = "20";
$additionalAttrs['multi_data'][] = $manufacturer;
```

to be used like:

```
    $productData = new stdClass();
    $additionalAttrs = array();

            // manufacturer from one of the two above ^

    $productData->name                   = $data['name']; 
    $productData->description            = $data['description'];
    $productData->short_description      = $data['short_description'];
    $productData->weight                 = 0;
    $productData->status                 = 2; // 1 = active
    $productData->visibility             = 4; //visible in search/catalog
    $productData->category_ids           = $data['categories']; 
    $productData->price                  = $data['price'];
    $productData->tax_class_id           = 2; // 2=standard
    $productData->additional_attributes  = $additionalAttrs;

    // Create new product
    try {
        $proxy->catalogProductCreate($sessionId, 'virtual', 9, $sku, $productData); // 9 is courses
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();  //Internal Error. Please see log for details.
        exit();
    }
```